# Error "Need more than zero items to unpack". (Using zip() and file Handling PYTHON 3)

Tags: python, file-handling

My code is supposed to add numbers, square them, and write to a file.

I have completed those parts and have written the code for the writing to file and reading to file.

However, I get the error that zero items have been written to file. I tried switching the "**list()**" around the **zip()** function  to a **[]**, but then received an error saying that " The function needed more than zero items to unpack"

What am I doing wrong?

```
nums=list(range(1,11))
conversion=list()

sumList=0

file_four = "/Users/battledrum/Desktop/file_four.txt"
file_five = "/Users/battledrum/Desktop/file_five.txt"
OUTPUT_FILE = "/Users/battledrum/Desktop/output.txt"

def add_numbers(lst):## add numbers in list
    sumList= sum(lst)
    return sumList

def sqr_numbers(lst):## square numbers in list
    for i in range(lst):
        lst[i]=pow(lst,2)

def num_to_string(lst):## convert to words
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i]==1:
           lst[i]="one"
        elif lst[i]==2:
           lst[i]="two"
        elif lst[i]==3:
           lst[i]="three"
        elif lst[i]==4:
           lst[i]="four"
        elif lst[i]==5:
           lst[i]="five"
        elif lst[i]==6:
           lst[i]="six"
        elif lst[i]==7:
           lst[i]="seven"
        elif lst[i]==8:
           lst[i]="eight"
        elif lst[i]==9:
           lst[i]="nine"
        elif lst[i]==10:
           lst[i]="ten"

    return conversion

def write_to_file():
    # load data pairs
    hts=list(zip(nums, conversion))

   # write output
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as outf:
        lines = ("{},{}".format(h, t) for h,t in hts)
        outf.write("\n".join(lines))
        print("{} lines written".format(len(hts)))        

def read_from_file(filename):
    for fin in open(filename):
       print(fin) 

sumList = add_numbers(nums)
conversion = num_to_string(nums)

write_to_file()
```

Comment: A bit off topic but surely you can use a dictionary in `num_to_string` instead of 10 elif statements?

Comment: dictionaries would be easier, but it's my kid sister's CS project and it requires her to use lists

Comment: No, I meant to use a dictionary to map the values in the list to their word equivalent. Also, doesn't `zip()` already return a list? Why do you need the `list()` function around it? Edit: `range(1,11)` also already returns a list. There's no need to wrap it in `list()`

Comment: I understood that. I just used only zip() and got this : TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len(). When I use only range() and not list(range()) i get this: range() does not support item assignment.

Comment: @tangrs, In Python 3 `range` returns a range object not a list.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. Additionally, please specify whether you are using Python 2 or 3, as it makes a *big* difference here.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Ah fair enough. In that case, it wrapping it in a `list()` may be necessary.

Comment: I use python 3. Testing the functions separately work and I get results from the num_to string() and add_numbers(). I believe the problem is with the zip().

Answer (score 2):

Don't use global variables.  `return` the computations from your functions.  Don't edit the list objects you pass in, because that changes the list that was passed in.  `nums` becomes `conversion`, for example.  Generate a new list in the function and return it.  I also show a simpler way to do the translation.

```
file_four = "file_four.txt"
file_five = "file_five.txt"
OUTPUT_FILE = "output.txt"

def add_numbers(lst):## add numbers in list
   sumList = sum(lst)
   return sumList

def sqr_numbers(lst):## square numbers in list
   for i in range(lst):
       lst[i]=pow(lst,2)

def num_to_string(lst):## convert to words
  # translation dictionary...better than if/elif/elif/...
  D = dict(zip(range(1,11),'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten'.split()))
  return [D[i] for i in lst]

def write_to_file(a,b):
   # load data pairs
   hts = list(zip(a,b))

   # write output
   with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "w") as outf:
      lines = ("{},{}".format(h, t) for h,t in hts)
      outf.write("\n".join(lines))
      print("{} lines written".format(len(hts)))

def read_from_file(filename):
   for fin in open(filename):
      print(fin)

nums = [1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8,10,9]
sumList = add_numbers(nums)
conversion = num_to_string(nums)
write_to_file(nums,conversion)
```

Output:

```
1,one
3,three
5,five
7,seven
2,two
4,four
6,six
8,eight
10,ten
9,nine
```

Comment: Cool use of dictionaries @Mark Tolonen. WORKS

Comment: Great answer but since this is essentially a homework question, I'm not sure if spoon-feeding the answer is necessarily benefiting the OP or future StackOverflow users.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't work because `sumList` and `conversion` are never changed. You cannot reassign global variables inside a function without using `global`. However, I would advise against doing that, and instead reassign the variables using the return values of the functions, like this:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
   for fin in open(filename):
      print(fin)

# CHANGE THESE TWO LINES
sumList = add_numbers(nums)
conversion = num_to_string(nums)

write_to_file()
```

Comment: I figured the same thing too. But I can't spot where. Since when I run the functions separately, they retune the expected results.

Comment: @BattleDrum. If you change those two lines, your example works as expected. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Regarding the `global` statement in your last line, I should add that I accidentally added that change in one of the edits to fix indentation to the OP. The original code the OP posted did not have it. My apologies

Comment: I just did and it does not.. I placed it just before the  write_to_file() call at the end of the code.

Comment: @tangrs. Thanks - now removed from my answer.

Comment: @BattleDrum. I tested it and it works fine for me. Make sure you use the code currently in the question and only change the two lines shown in my answer.

Comment: @ekhumoro You changed nothing about my code except add that line to it. And where did you add it> And are you using python 3?

Comment: @BattleDrum. See my updated answer. Use the **exact** code that is currently in your question.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have edited the question based on your exact instructions. It's still not working. Could you check to see where I am going wrong?

Comment: @BattleDrum. What do you mean by "it's still not working"? For me, it prints `10 lines written` and I get an output file with ten lines like this `one,one`, `two,two`, etc. What do you get?

Comment: The OP mutated `nums` in `num_to_string`.  That didn't look intended.  The first column looks like it should be the original integers.

Comment: @MarkTolonen. Yeah, the example is clearly unfinished (it's basically homework, judging by the initial comments to the question). I was just trying to deal with the issue regarding assigning to globals.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is at the following line in `def num_to_string(lst):`

```
  conversion=lst
```

Due to the way Python scopes variables, `conversion` is a local variable. You're not assigning to the global `conversion` variable.

If you modify the top of the function to look like this:

```
def num_to_string(lst):## convert to words
  global conversion 
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    # ...
```

It works perfectly since you're telling Python to use the global variable `conversion` instead of creating a new local variable.

It's the same deal with your `write_to_file()` function. However, because your code reads the conversion variable before writing to it, Python uses the global variable instead.

However, a better and cleaner way is to avoid referencing global variables in function declarations in the first place. Instead, have functions work on a set of inputs that are passed as parameters and return the output.

Testing was done in Python 2.7 and 3.5.1.

Comment: Was it able to write to file and read as expected? And i use python 3

Comment: Why don't you try it for yourself?

Comment: You'll need to be far more specific than that. What doesn't work exactly? On my machine, it produces `10 lines written` and a text file with 10 lines in it as expected.

Comment: If it tells me that zero lines are written it means that the lists (conversion and num) don't contain any items. But when I call the functions that fill these lists with values, I get the expected result i.e.: for num [1,2,3.....10] and for conversion["one", "two",......"ten"]. This is the error  i get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 73, in <module>
    write_to_file()
   60, in write_to_file
    print("{} lines written".format(len(hts)))
TypeError: object of type 'zip' has no len()

Comment: I'm not sure where you're at exactly. As I take it, you've made the modifications to the code posted in the question, ran it and the output is still `0 lines written`. Is that correct?

Comment: You need to start fresh. Take the posted code in the question, make the appropriate modifications and run it. It sounds like you're running something different to the code posted in the original question since I am unable to reproduce the error you have.

Comment: Could the down voter explain what was wrong with this answer?